# What is meaning of the file object?

Tags: python, file

In python to open a file we write `with open(filename) as f:` or `f=open(filename)`. Can anyone please give more knowledge of what is **f** and what it will do?

Comment: object of type File

Comment: why can't you print `type(f)` it in python interpreter, it will tell you

Comment: read the docs for 'open' https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: `f` is a variable. in python, you don't have to declare it.

Answer (score 1):

**f** is file `object` that contain the `state of the file`

few methods:

> f.mode - The mode attribute of a file object tells you in which mode
>   the file was opened.
>
> f.name - The name attribute of a file object tells you the name of the
>   file that the file object has open.
>
> f.closed - The closed attribute of a file object indicates whether the
>   object has a file open or not. In this case, the file is still open
>   (closed is False).
>
> f.close() - To close a file, call the close method of the file object.
>
> f.seek(0) - The seek method of a file object moves to another position
>   in the open file
>
> f.tell() - The tell method of a file object tells you your current
>   position in the open file
>
> f.read() - T0 read the content of file

Answer (score 0):

When you write `F = open(filename)` in Python, you are saving the object returned by the call to `open()` on `filename` into a variable.  The variable is called `F`, in your case, but it could be `file` or `puppy` if you wanted.

The `open` function in Python returns a Python file object (Python glossary on [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)). So after that declaration, `F` is a file object - but I think your question was more about whether `F` was a Python keyword that contributed to the code, and I think you can see now that the answer to that is "No, it is an arbitrary variable name" basically.  It is not quite an *arbitrary* variable name - people use `F` a lot (so I can see why you thought it was a keyword), but it's used frequently in this instatiation because people are thinking 'F' for 'file'.

You can learn more about the `open` function over here in its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are assigning to a variable named F a file object wrapper. It's done to make further operations on that same instance file object.